# Are default ACL in Linux a security flaw?

Tags: linux

I'm currently learning the Linux system and I have a question about the default Linux ACL.
On my virtual machine, all files created are set with the default permissions as follows:

```
-rw- rw- r--
```

According to this permission level, any other user on the system could see the newly created file knowing the **path** and the **file name**.
This could lead to a typical path traversal attack.
Taking advantage of this attack looks even more easy on multi-users systems.
For example, a server where all students use the same folders names for the same lessons, and the same file names. One could just go ahead and create a script checking files creations in this directory and get the content as soon as it is created.

Other point, some folders are common in each home directory, typically the "Documents" folder.
Even with a home directory set as follows:

```
-rwx --- ---
```

We can still access and read the content we guessed.
I'm aware that path traversal attacks are not new but my question is:

- Why are the permissions not more restrictive?
- What can we do to defend against this except by *chmoding* every new
  file creation even before adding content to it? (if we are not the root user)

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no "standard Linux ACL". Default file permissions can vary by system and by distribution; *most* distributions seem to have default permissions of `644` or `664`, but that's not inherent to the Linux kernel, and the proper `umask` depends on the system.

More broadly: whether files are defaulted to world-readable is a security flaw or not strongly depends on what specific threats you are concerned about. If default permissions are world-readable, that means all users on the system can read files not specifically marked private. That's not necessarily a bug -- in a multiuser environment, you could plausibly declare that users will typically be sharing files, and provide a `~/private/` directory by default for files that they *don't* want to be shared; people can by default read anything directly under your home directory, but on the flipside sharing is easier. There's a tradeoff, which is often worth making.

Furthermore, the default permissions on *files* don't change on a per-folder basis. If users want to keep some things private and share other things, and don't want to `chmod` lots of things, you *have* to set permissive default permissions. You then make certain folders which will have private stuff have more restrictive permissions. You can't do the reverse; if you want to make it possible at all to have someone have a `Public` directory without learning `chmod`, you basically *have* to implement it this way. It's really easy to restrict access to a file beyond what's in its permissions; *granting* access beyond its permissions is not possible (you have to change the permissions).

That's because you're wrong when you say that a `0700` home directory doesn't secure anything. A folder's `x` bit controls access within the directory. If a user has no execute permission on `/example/directory/`, then they cannot access *anything* within `/example/directory/`. Even if they know that `/example/directory/a` is a file. Even if they have read permissions on that file. Even if they *own* that file: you can't access a file unless you not only have the permissions on that file, but *also* have execute permissions on *all* parent directories of that file. The implication is that you can secure a subdirectory much more easily than you can make an especially open one.

In your case, the `Documents` directory is `700`; probably the other "user-friendly" directories (this is an awful term for it, but I mean things like `Documents`, `Desktop`, `Downloads`, `Music`, etc. -- stuff that's designed for the average user to use to hold their normal files) are as well. Provided you store your documents there and not in custom subdirectories of your home directory (or directly in your home directory), no one else has access. Your home directory is intended to contain mostly config files that are expected to be there; most personal files are meant to go in a default (secured) subdirectory. If you store things directly in a home directory, they're visible, but that's not what your OS is pushing you to do. If you create a new subdirectory of `~` and want it private, set its permissions to `700`; if you want it public, set it to `755` (if you want people to be able to access files if and only if they know the name, `711`). But the expectation is that your private stuff doesn't go straight in `~`, and that the places your documents do go is already secured.

Comment: @Mike You're welcome! If this answer solved your problem, you can [accept it](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the checkbox next to it.

Answer (score 0):

The umask command allows you to change the mask used for file creation which changes the default permissions.

More details on the various modes here:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html